# How can I keep the contents even if I refresh it?

Tags: javascript

```
const Form = document.querySelector(".tracker-form"),
      Name = document.querySelector(".tracker-name"),
      Date = document.querySelector(".tracker-date"),
      Amount = document.querySelector(".tracker-amount"),
      Table = document.querySelector(".tracker-table"),
      tableRow = document.createElement("tr");

      
function deleteRow(event) {
    event.target.closest('tr').remove();
}

function addExpense() {
    Form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
        const tableName = document.createElement("td");
        const tableDate = document.createElement("td");
        const tableAmount = document.createElement("td");

        const delButton = document.createElement("button"); 
        delButton.innerHTML = "X";
        delButton.addEventListener("click", deleteRow);
        
        Table.appendChild(tableRow);

        tableRow.appendChild(tableName);
        tableRow.appendChild(tableDate);
        tableRow.appendChild(tableAmount);
        tableRow.appendChild(delButton);
        tableName.innerHTML = Name.value;
        tableDate.innerHTML = Date.value;
        tableAmount.innerHTML = `${Amount.value} $`;

        Name.value = "";
        Date.value = "";
        Amount.value = "";

        event.preventDefault();
    })
}

function init() {
    addExpense();
}

init();
```

In this code, when i refresh it in browser, all of the table contents i submit as Name, Date, Amount value is initialize(gone). I want to keep it even if i refresh the page. How can i do it?

Comment: You have to make sure the server provides all the appropriate values for the form. Exactly how you do that varies tremendously based on your basic server-side language and framework and on your application's purpose.

Comment: you can save them to localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not directly possible unless you use some format of a storage mechanism to store the data and whenever you load the form you use the stored data to populate your form.

Most common way people do it is to store it in the browser localstorage. However note that you can only store strings there.

So create an object of all the data you want to persist even after refreshing
use `JSON.stringify` method to convert object to string

there are methods to handle data in localstorage using

```
localStorage.setItem("formData", JSON.stringify(data));
localStorage.getItem("formData");
localStorage.removeItem("formData");
```

here data object is whatever you want to store

just make sure that on loading your form, you first get a data object using `localStorage.getItem()` convert it to object using `JSON.parse(data);` populate your fields.

At last make sure to remove the data whenever you're done with the action you wanted to perform.

Comment: Thank you:) i have to study more about localStorage then.

Comment: won't be much hard, just knowing what it is and then these basic 3 methods should be sufficient for many of the use cases